# plotting logs of numbers: typeerror: only size -1 arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

code snippet:

x = np.arange(.2,2,.1)
y = -20*math.log10((4*np.pi*(dist*m_nM)*(x*1e+9)/c))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

results in this error:
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Change `math.log` to `np.log`